# Sync Records from one database to other with using different server or machine

Tags: java, mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have two different database in different machine.Both the have same tables and i just want insert or update records from one machine to other. how can i do same with using mysql database.

Suppose one of my system is on India.and other one is on USA.

It is not web based Application.

Comment: did you get your solution? @sweety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you probably want to make one of the databases act as a slave to the other, that way any updates on the master will be automatically propagated to the slave. The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) has quite a lot of detail on this.

If you wanted to be able to make updates to either database and have them replicated to the other I think it is also possible to configure MySQL to use multi-master replication.

Comment: I don't want sync whole table...I just want sync row level records only and that could be run only on demand.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to have different data in the two databases?

Comment: MySQL replication will only transmit the changes over the network not the entire table. Not sure about running on demand though, although the slave connection doesn't have to run all the time so you could just start it when required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate replication tool such as SymmetricDS (http://symmetricds.codehaus.org/) which can sync 2 databases. But beware that you will surely face conflicts problems if you make modifications in both databases.