# Java and shadow copy databases/datasources

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, datasource

I trying to search in Google, Hibernate documentation, Spring Documentation some information:

How I can configure my data sources in Spring Framework for create additional shadow copy of my MySQL db?

Shadow copy - I mean: We have 02 db, 01 is primary, 02 is backup/shadow.

Shadow DB - it's when in 02 db we have full copy of 01 db, and all other SQL it's only UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, ALTER(modification), without SELECT. DB structure and data is same.

Other words we have 02 data sources, and I need configure this data sources like: 01 is Primary, 02 only for UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, ALTER(modification), without SELECT.

Maybe who know some Java library/tools?

I need full and simple, in real time copy of db to another one.

my English on basic level.

Comment: Your question might be similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133002/sync-records-from-one-database-to-other-with-using-different-server-or-machine

Comment: I suggest you google for database replication (Master/Slave replication) although cannot grasp your use case.

Comment: @MarkR say: MySQL replication is not "reliable", nor is it able to automatically re-sync if it goes wrong. [stackoverflow.com/questions/7331776](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331776/mysql-replication-master-to-slave?answertab=votes#tab-top) and I have no access to my.cnf or my.ini